# Do not show any rows when the LastUpdated time of LAST_VALUE is within criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this T-SQL inventory script running every once and a while. It retrieves basic statistics info and places it into a table appropriately named StatisticsInfo.
So every run of the script a new entry for every statistic is placed into this table.

When I query the StatisticsInfo table using the following query (simplified):

```
SELECT CollectionTime,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName ORDER BY CollectionTime) AS Run,
       TableName,
       StatisticName,
       ColumnName,
       LastUpdated,
       Rows,
       RowsSampled,
       HistogramSteps,
       RowsModified
FROM dbo.StatisticsInfo
```

I get the following results:

```
CollectionTime      Run TableName           StatisticName               ColumnName  LastUpdated                 Rows        RowsSampled HistogramSteps  RowsModified
...
2020-10-09 11:23:57 1   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2973644
2020-10-09 11:28:17 2   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2973840
2020-10-09 11:31:52 3   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2973967
2020-10-09 11:50:18 4   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2974812
2020-10-09 12:01:35 5   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2975294
2020-10-09 12:52:41 6   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-10-09 12:32:01.2233333 59219944    59219944    200             561
...
```

As you can see in the last row (Run #6), the stats for Column UITSLAG have recently been updated.

When I add a WHERE clause to identify statistics that have not been updated in the last month, I run into my issue.

```
SELECT CollectionTime,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName ORDER BY CollectionTime) AS Run,
       TableName,
       StatisticName,
       ColumnName,
       LastUpdated,
       Rows,
       RowsSampled,
       HistogramSteps,
       RowsModified
FROM dbo.StatisticsInfo
WHERE LastUpdated < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

The result still shows all the previous Runs of my inventory script:

```
CollectionTime      Run TableName           StatisticName               ColumnName  LastUpdated                 Rows        RowsSampled HistogramSteps  RowsModified
...
2020-10-09 11:23:57 1   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2973644
2020-10-09 11:28:17 2   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2973840
2020-10-09 11:31:52 3   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2973967
2020-10-09 11:50:18 4   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2974812
2020-10-09 12:01:35 5   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200             2975294
...
```

I know the statistics for this column have been updated, so I do not want to show any previous Runs.

So next I tried using LAST_VALUE.

```
SELECT CollectionTime,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName ORDER BY CollectionTime) AS Run,
       TableName,
       StatisticName,
       StatisticType,
       ColumnName,
       LastUpdated,
       LAST_VALUE(LastUpdated) OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName ORDER BY LastUpdated) AS LastUpdatedMax,
       Rows,
       RowsSampled,
       HistogramSteps,
       RowsUnfiltered,
       RowsModified
FROM DBA.dbo.StatisticsInfo
WHERE LastUpdated < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

That also does not get me there, since it only shows up in the last row, which already has the most recent date.

```
CollectionTime      Run TableName           StatisticName               ColumnName  LastUpdated                 LastUpdatedMax              Rows        RowsSampled HistogramSteps
...
2020-10-09 11:23:57 1   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200 
2020-10-09 11:28:17 2   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200 
2020-10-09 11:31:52 3   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200
2020-10-09 11:50:18 4   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200 
2020-10-09 12:01:35 5   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 2020-05-11 03:00:23.9500000 57648845    57648845    200
2020-10-09 12:52:41 6   LAB_HUIDIGE_UITSLAG _WA_Sys_00000004_0D1ADB2A   UITSLAG     2020-10-09 12:32:01.2233333 2020-10-09 12:32:01.2233333 59219944    59219944    200
...
```

This query gets the result I want, but I think it's not the most efficient way.

```
SELECT CollectionTime,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName ORDER BY CollectionTime) AS Run,
       TableName,
       StatisticName,
       StatisticType,
       ColumnName,
       LastUpdated,
       (
           SELECT MAX(LastUpdated)
           FROM DBA.dbo.StatisticsInfo
           WHERE TableName = si.TableName
                 AND StatisticName = si.StatisticName
           GROUP BY TableName,
                    StatisticName
       ) AS LastUpdatedMax,
       Rows,
       RowsSampled,
       HistogramSteps,
       RowsModified
FROM DBA.dbo.StatisticsInfo AS si
WHERE (
          SELECT MAX(LastUpdated)
          FROM DBA.dbo.StatisticsInfo
          WHERE TableName = si.TableName
                AND StatisticName = si.StatisticName
          GROUP BY TableName,
                   StatisticName
      ) < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Mark

Comment: Are you not therefore after `>` not `<`?

Comment: You also say *"I tried using LAG, LEAD. FIRST_VALUE, LAST_VALUE in a variety of ways, but I was unsuccessful."* but then don't show those attempts or explain why they didn't work. Help us help you.

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put attempts in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` as this clause defines the frame starting from the first row and ending at the last row of the partition.

```
SELECT CollectionTime,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName ORDER BY CollectionTime) AS Run,
       TableName,
       StatisticName,
       StatisticType,
       ColumnName,
       LastUpdated,
       LAST_VALUE(LastUpdated) OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName 
                   ORDER BY LastUpdated RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
                            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LastUpdatedMax,
       Rows,
       RowsSampled,
       HistogramSteps,
       RowsUnfiltered,
       RowsModified
FROM DBA.dbo.StatisticsInfo
WHERE LastUpdated < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

To reference the LastUpdatedMax value in the where clause of query place the Select statement containing the windowing function in common table expresssion.  Something like this

```
with s_cte as (
    SELECT CollectionTime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName ORDER BY CollectionTime) AS Run,
           TableName,
           StatisticName,
           StatisticType,
           ColumnName,
           LastUpdated,
           LAST_VALUE(LastUpdated) OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, StatisticName 
                       ORDER BY LastUpdated RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
                                UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LastUpdatedMax,
           Rows,
           RowsSampled,
           HistogramSteps,
           RowsUnfiltered,
           RowsModified
    FROM DBA.dbo.StatisticsInfo)
WHERE s.LastUpdatedMax < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Wow! That indeed results in a LastUpdatedMax column with the values I expect. But then how do I filter all rows in a partition from the result, since I cannot use a windowing function in the where clause?

Comment: To filter on the result of windowing functions you could place the query in a common table expression.